# AR - Annotation to a fix Location

Tags: iphone

I made an augmented reality Application, there I have an arrow points on the z-axis to the location (longitude & latitude) of one shop now I'd like to make an annotation in the "sky" which points direct on the shop coordinate. I found some projects on github, like iPhone-AR-Toolkit, but I don't understand this.
Is there a simple way to add such an annotation above the location?

**Edit:**
After searching a lot I find a pdf document in de web, which contains some code for that what I want, but the problem is, I don't understand it and it doesn't do the things right.
**The Code:**

```
// Artificial Horizon - compensate for rotation along x-axis
// need to know the field of view of the camera to find horizon position inside of camera view
// about 53 degrees vertical and 37.5 degrees horizontal

// for directional Horizon - artificial horizon pegged to a specific cardinal direction (North)

// in (void)viewDidAppear
// Load the image to show in the overlay
UIImage *overlayGraphic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Punkt.png"];
overlayGraphicView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayGraphic];
overlayGraphicView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 50, 50);
[self addSubview:overlayGraphicView];

[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];

locationManager = [[CoreLocationMangager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

- (void) updateUI {
    CGPoint overlayCenter = [overlayGraphicView center];
    overlayCenter.y = 240.0 - 537.8 * sin(vertAngle);
    overlayCenter.x = 160.0 - 497.8 * sin((magCompassHeadingInDeg) * (M_PI / 180.0));
    [overlayGraphicView setCenter:overlayCenter];
    overlayGraphicView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    vertAngle = -atan2(acceleration.y, acceleration.z) - M_PI/2.0;
    vertAngleInDeg = vertAngle * 180.0f/M_PI;

    angle = -atan2(acceleration.y, acceleration.x) - M_PI/2.0;
    angleInDeg = angle * 180.0f / M_PI;

    [self updateUI];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    magCompassHeadingInDeg = [newHeading magneticHeading];
    [self updateUI];
}
```

There is an image View is added to a camera overlay, and this image should point to North - but my problem is it also points to South. How can i fix that? And can anybody explain me thr values from the overlayCenter.y and .x - I don't understand them.

Comment: I want that an image points to a special location. The image should always on the same y point, so its static in the heigh from the screen of the device, but it should move around the x axis to point, for example to north.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Specify an **altitude** to specify the height from sea-level that is z-axis.

Mixare SDK will allow you to specify and load your **POI's with latitude, longitude and altitude.**

You can refer it from [here](https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone)

I have used this sdk and it works great and allows you specify Altitude.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but Mixare is so extensive - I look for a simple solution - if there is one ...

Comment: Well its extensive but easy to use...even i have searched on this a lot to get the z-axis and i could get only mixare SDK and its quite easy to use if we understand the flow of the views..If any issues do let me know..:)